# Load image for each second

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have a PHP page that calls a JavaScript function on another page in order to load one of 60 images (1 for each second). Each image has a number in its name (i.e. 1-60) and when the user presses the button the image that is loaded corresponds to the second when the button is pressed.

I have the JavaScript page returning the current seconds but I cannot seem to reference the correct image name. Is this a JavaScript syntax problem or should the 'seconds' variable be captured separately through Ajax:

```
<img src=<?php echo image-1.jpg' ) ?> id="imageX" />
<div id="mySec">Seconds</div>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction_1()">Function_1</button>

<script>
    function myFunction_1() {
        var d = new Date();
        var x = document.getElementById("mySec");
        x.innerHTML=d.getSeconds();
        var z = d.getSeconds();
        document.getElementById("imageX").src="<?php echo 'image-' . "z". '.jpg' ?>" ;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You cannot mix PHP and JavaScript like that and expect it to work. PHP runs on the server, and JavaScript runs in the browser.

Comment: Thanks @Matt - so if I were to use Ajax how would I do it.

Comment: You shouldn't need ajax at all. You're using (trying to use) PHP to build a string. Just do it with JavaScript string concatenation instead.

Comment: I have tried a variation of concatenations but cannot seem to get this to connect. What do you suggest...

Comment: Did you try `document.getElementById("imageX").src='image-' + z + '.jpg';`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
<img src="image-1.jpg" id="imageX" />
```

And:

```
<script>
    function myFunction_1() {
        var d = new Date();
        var x = document.getElementById("mySec");
        var z = d.getSeconds();
        x.innerHTML = z + ' Seconds';
        document.getElementById("imageX").src = 'image-' + z + '.jpg';
    }
</script>
```

No need for PHP at all.

Comment: Thanks @iambriansreed yes this worked - it is the + sign that made it.